# Finding the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{a^{n+1} -1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let's say I have a power series $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{a^{n+1} -1}$ where $a$ is some constant greater than $1$.

How do I calculate the radius of convergence of this series?

I know that the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{{\limsup{|c_n|}^\frac{1}{n}}}$ for the coefficient sequence $c_n$, but I don't understand how to find that in this case.  $c_n = a^{n+1} -1$, but how can I find the $\limsup$ of this?

Comment: It is $\infty$, but you chose the wrong $c_n$. It should be the reciprocal.

Comment: Of course you can. It is $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a > 1$, you have $1 < a-a^{-n} < a$ for $n$ large anough. Therefore, $\sqrt[n]{a-a^{-n}}\to 1$. Thus
$$
\sqrt[n]{a^{n+1}-1} = a\sqrt[n]{a-a^{-n}}\to a.
$$
This should help.